# MongoDB - many-many relationship select row that match a set of values

Tags: mongodb, many-to-many, database

I am working on a solution for my company and I've a problem related to MongoDb to solve. We are building a mapping between Products and Suppliers. The simplified structure of the documents is the following:

```
Product
{
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "any-product",
},

Supplier
{
    "id" : "99",
    "name" : "ACME",
    "products" : [1,....] //list of products that the suppliers can supply
}
```

When we need to place an order we would like to place it to the least number of suppliers....the best is that only one supplier can supply the entire order.

That's the problem: I need to select all the suppliers that can supply ALL the product in a given list.

I'm new to MongoDB and I did various tests but I could not find a solution....anyway I think that the solution is not so simple.
Consider that I can also change the structure of the DB to meet these need. Feel free to propose a different approach.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are supplier names guaranteed to be unique? Are products only provided by a single supplier? Can suppliers change during the lifetime of the productin your application? Am I correct to assume that both suppliers and products have additional fields attached? What if the "order" can *not* be processed by a single supplier?

Comment: 1. We can suppose that supplier names are unique.
2. No, products can be provided by more than one supplier
3. To simplify the scenario, we assume that suppliers cannot change
4. Yes, they have additional fiels..that is only a minimal subset
5. The software select the minumum number of suppliers to fulfill the order